# Merge two array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two almost identical arrays of objects, the only difference between them is that the first array consists of inner arrays with objects having a `text1` attribute, and the second array has `text2` property instead. Each array contains 800 objects with same keys `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` ....

How can I merge these two arrays? I tried with `push` function but got only the first array. Is there some other way to merge two arrays like `reduce`, `filter` or some other function?

```
let arr1 = [{
    "1": [{
        "text1": "Some text 1",
        "englishName": "Name 1",
        "number": 1,
      },
      {
        "text1": "Some text 2",
        "englishName": "Name 2",
        "number": 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "2": [{
        "text1": "Some text 3",
        "englishName": "Name 3",
        "number": 3,
      },
      {
        "text1": "Some text 4",
        "englishName": "Name 4",
        "number": 4,
      }
    ]
  }
]

let arr2 = [{
    "1": [{
        "text2": "Some new text",
        "englishName": "Name 1",
        "number": 1
      },
      {
        "text2": "Some new text 2",
        "englishName": "Name 2",
        "number": 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "2": [{
        "text2": "Some new text 3",
        "englishName": "Name 3",
        "number": 3,
      },
      {
        "text2": "Some new text 4",
        "englishName": "Name 4",
        "number": 4,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need to merge in one array and concat text2 to first array like this

```
  let mergearray = [
  {
  "1": [
   {
    "text1": "Some text 1",
    "text2": "Some new text 1",
    "englishName": "Name 1",
    "number": 1,
   },
   {
    "text1": "Some text 2",
    "text2": "Some new text 2",
    "englishName": "Name 2",
    "number": 2,
  }
  ]
  },
 {
 "2": [
   {
    "text1": "Some text 3",
    "text2": "Some new text 3",
    "englishName": "Name 3",
    "number": 3,
   },
   {
    "text1": "Some text 4",
    "text2": "Some new text 4",
    "englishName": "Name 4",
    "number": 4,
   } ] } ]
```

How compare keys of arrays?

Comment: Add a desired output and what you have tried so far please.

Comment: Can you share the desired output as well? Do you want `text2` fields to be converted to `text1`?

Comment: i need this result let mergearray = [
    {
    "1": [
      {
        "text1": "Some text 1",
        "text2": "Some new text 1",
        "englishName": "Name 1",
        "number": 1,
      },
      {
        "text1": "Some text 2",
        "text2": "Some new text 2",
        "englishName": "Name 2",
        "number": 2,
      }] }

Comment: i try with push let merge= []   for(let i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) {
                merged.push({
                ...arr2[i], 
                ...arr1[i]
                });
              }

Comment: @Ismeet check my answer you will get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const arr3 = arr1.reduce((acc, item, index, array) => {
  if (arr2.length > index) {
    array[index][index + 1][0].text2 = arr2[index][index + 1][0].text2;
    acc = array.map((item, index2) => {
      return item[index2 + 1][0];
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3.reverse()))
```

Comment: it's because I made the reduce return an object. Check the an answer again you will see that I updated it to return an array.

Comment: looks like i didn't get the desired result. I only have one in each item. I update my desired output.

Comment: this is desire uotput let mergearray = [
  {
  "1": [
   {
    "text1": "Some text 1",
    "text2": "Some new text 1",
    "englishName": "Name 1",
    "number": 1,
   },
   {
    "text1": "Some text 2",
    "text2": "Some new text 2",
    "englishName": "Name 2",
    "number": 2,
  }
  ]
  },
 {
 "2": [
   {
    "text1": "Some text 3",
    "text2": "Some new text 3",
    "englishName": "Name 3",
    "number": 3,
   },
   {
    "text1": "Some text 4",
    "text2": "Some new text 4",
    "englishName": "Name 4",
    "number": 4,
   } ] } ]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `JavaScript Array concat()` method
the `concat()` method is used to **join two or more arrays**.
This method does not change the existing arrays, it returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays. you can do that like this

```
let arr= arr1.concat(arr2); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

it will give you this result

```
[{"1":[{"text1":"Some text 1","englishName":"Name 1","number":1},{"text1":"Some text 2","englishName":"Name 2","number":2}]},
{"2":[{"text1":"Some text 3","englishName":"Name 3","number":3},{"text1":"Some text 4","englishName":"Name 4","number":4}]},
{"1":[{"text2":"Some new text","englishName":"Name 1","number":1},{"text2":"Some new text 2","englishName":"Name 2","number":2}]},
{"2":[{"text2":"Some new text 3","englishName":"Name 3","number":3},{"text2":"Some new text 4","englishName":"Name 4","number":4}]}]
```

Comment: i need to merge in one array and concat text2 to firt array like this let mergearray = [ { "1": [ { "text1": "Some text 1", "text2": "Some new text 1", "englishName": "Name 1", "number": 1, }, { "text1": "Some text 2", "text2": "Some new text 2", "englishName": "Name 2", "number": 2, }] } –